# Open source version control projects for video/music editing

Tags: git, video

Due to the broad scope of the original question, the question's scope has been boiled down to:

### Which projects already exist that allow for the version control tracking for video/music/picture editting?

---

Becoming more familiar with `git`, I have begun to really seen the power of version control, push/pull, commits, branches,merging,etc...

How could you implement the `git` software with video editing or music editing?

Although I'm not a video or music editor myself, friends commonly do 'file'-> 'save as' constantly.  Creating filenames like:

1. foo1
2. foo1-bar
3. foo2-bar-foo

Ultimately you begin to run into the same problems `git` attempts to solve.

Merging 2 videos becomes almost impossible and determining your currently **up to date** version becomes crazy.

Assuming this functionality can be implemented, how would I go about doing this?
Are there other projects already existence with the goal of implementing a git like concept for video editing/music editing?

Not knowing much about video encoding or video editing myself, could `git` work with Adobe Photoshop files?

---

*Although this isn't only programming related, the implementation of the concept is, and considering `git` is actively used by programmers this is arguable the best place to get relevant answers to this question.*

Comment: I thinks this is not only `git` related but versioning for other than text files in general. Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186/best-versioning-tools-to-use-for-photoshop-illustrator-and-related-binary-files

Comment: Closers please leave comments. Monitoring video encoding and changes is completely relevant with programming.

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292/version-control-for-graphics

Comment: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.  Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." -- [The SO FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: @cdhowie question edited for a narrower scope

Comment: Ehn, but now it falls under the category of "every answer is equally valid."  This seems like it would be better asked at superuser anyway.

Comment: @cdhowie what if the question became a community wiki?

Comment: Off-topic community wiki questions are still off-topic.  :/

Comment: @chowie How is asking "available open source version control projects for video/music editting" off topic?  In that case any `git` question is off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search Google for "git" and "FUSE". There are first tries in generating a "Git filesystem", that stores stuff in a Git repository. (Under Linux and Mac OS X, that is.)

However, they have the same problems that you describe: What do you do in the case of conflicts, ...